# How to determine the value that the remaining select needs to bind based on a select option？

Tags: angular

I want the first select can dynamically change another select value.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="modal-body">

          <p><strong>Rate:</strong></p> {{ApplesPerCash}}  <p><strong> kg / Pound </strong></p>

          <p>Action:         
            <select name="actions" formControlName="action" ng-model="state">
              <option value="fromMarket">Get Apple from Market(Buyer:user,Seller:market)</option>
              <option value="fromSupplier">Get Apple from Supplier(Buyer:market,Seller:supplier)</option>
            </select>
          </p>

          <div class="form-group text-left" ng-if="state==fromMarket">
            <p>Buyer: 
              <select name="buyer" formControlName="formBuyerID">
                <option *ngFor="let buyer of allBuyers" value="{{buyer.buyerID}}">{{buyer.buyerID}}</option>
              </select>
            </p>    
            <p>Seller: 
              <select name="seller" formControlName="formSellerID">
                <option *ngFor="let seller of allSellers" value="{{seller.sellerID}}">{{seller.sellerID}}</option>
              </select>
            </p> 
          </div>

          <div class="form-group text-left">
            <label for="cashValue">Apple weight:</label>

              <input formControlName="appleWeight" type="number" step='any' class="form-control">

          </div>
```

As the code above shows, buyer and seller are different depending on the choice of the first select, so the remaining selects change the data binding based on the choice of the first select. What should I do? There is also how to write in `ngOnInit ()`, because there has been an error: ERROR `Error: Must supply a value for form control with name:'action'.`

this is my ngOnInit()

```
  constructor(private serviceCashToApples: CashToApplesService, fb: FormBuilder) {
this.myForm = fb.group({
  action: this.action,
});

ngOnInit(): void {
if(this.action.value == "fromMarket") {
  this.loadAllUsers()
  .then(() => {
    this.loadAllMarkets();
  });
}

if(this.action.value == "fromSupplier") {
  this.loadAllMarkets()
  .then(() => {
    this.loadAllSuppliers();
  });
}

this.action.value == "fromMarket";

this.loadAllUsers()
.then(() => {
  this.loadAllMarkets();
});
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work with.

Comment: Is this all that you have? Can you show the component class? How is your reactive form defined?

Comment: @emcee22 I have show the component class

Comment: can you add a stackblitz ?

Comment: @bubbles https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpjezy , I replaced my content in HTML and component. TS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by parts.

If you use ReactiveForm, you can use in .html myForm.get('action').value=='fromMarket' and not use the referenceVariable "market" and ngModel -I don't want to say that it's incorrect. It's only another option I prefer.

In reactiveForm it's more clear subscribe to valuesChange if you want to control when the user choice fromMarket or fromBuyer. So you can do some like

```
ngOnInit()
{
this.myForm = fb.group({
  action: this.action,
  fromBuyerId:'',
  fromSellerId:''
});
this.myForm.get('action').valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
    if (res=='fromMarket')
    {
        .....
    }

    if (res=='fromMarket')
    {
        .....
    }
})
}
```

See that you create the whole formGroup. A fromGroup exist even there'are no input or not .html. The inputs makes easy change the value, but are two concepts independent.

When we create the form in an ngOnInit, to avoid initials error we can use a *ngIf

```
<form *ngIf="myForm [formGroup]="myForm">
    ...
</form>
```

I don't know about your functions loadAllUsers and loadAllMarket. Well they looks like promises inside the own component. In general, you should create a service to get the data and susbcribe -if you use observables- or use then -if you use Promises- in the component. The reason is that, along the developer of your application the way to get data can change -e.g. at first you decided was fixed, after from a .json file, after from a database.. And you don't want change the component, else the service.

By The way, In your code I can not see difference if the user choose fromMarket or fromSeller when you execute loadAllUser and loadAllMArket. If there are independent, just read at first in the ngOnInit

Comment: I added your code in my app, but still existed that error.

Comment: It works, and how to set the default option. I think the problem is that I never set the default option, so the error always exists.

Comment: when you get the allBuyers and allSeller you can use `this.myForm.get('formBuyerID').setValue(allBuyer[0].buyerID)` and `this.myForm.get('fromSellerID').setValue(allSeller[0].sellerID)`